# Why is Python printing escape sequences in hex?

Tags: python-3.x, hex, escaping

In the Python IDLE, when I enter `'\b'`, it returns `'\x08'`. How can I print it as an actual backspace to erase a character?

PS: Python 3.8.4

PPS: `'\n'`, `'\t'`, and `'\r'` return `'\n'`, `'\t'`, and `'\r'` respectively.